# How to handle the number of threads to be executed python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

I'd like you help with this easy/hard question.

I'm working with python threads. This is my code:

```
import threading
#import class1, class2, class3 . . .

def main():

   list = [class1(), class2(), class3() . . .]
   for obj in list:
      t = threading.Thread(target=obj.run, )
      t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

I want only executing two of them at the first, and when one of them finishes then the third one and so on

Is there a way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **join** method

```
def main():

   list = [class1(), class2()] #only two
   waiting_list = []
   for obj in list:
       t = threading.Thread(target=obj.run, )
       t.start()
       waiting_list.append(t)
   for t in waiting_list:
       print("Waiting for %s" % t)
       t.join()
       print("%s done!" % t)
   list = [class3(), class4()] #more stuff

   for obj in list:
       t = threading.Thread(target=obj.run, )
       t.start()
   #and so on
```

Also look the concurrent.futures package for a more high level thread pool to avoid the for loops

Comment: This may be a good solution by now, but, it seems that the threads will be going two by two... no problem, I'll use it, thank you

Comment: You can use this code to make function that takes two classes each time and call it from a loop ...